# How to append an XML file in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing an XML file to the sd card, and I need to be able to open that XML file and append data to it. How can I accomplish this? For example, my XML file is:

```
<items>
    <item attr="value">data</item>
    <item attr="value2">data 2</item>
</items>
```

I later need to open this XML file and append a new item to it:

```
<item attr="value3">data 3</item>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sax parser that reads the file, outputs all elements by default and when it finds the closing {}, first insert the new item, then the closing tag.

Sax parsers are available by default in Android.

One example on how to deal with Sax at all [can be found here](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/Board.java#L30).

Comment: the link only provides the class it doesn't provide how to use it, can you please relate it my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42528154/6854117) ?

Comment: Actually lines 30-60 indeed show how this can be used. Googling for "using a sax parser in java" for example reveals this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to obtain a [Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) class version of your XML file. You can do this using a DOM Parser. From the Document class you can then manipulate it and write it back out with your modifications.

Here's code on DOM parsing.

```
     DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = docBuilder.parse(myfilepath);
```

More information on different approaches to XML in Android can be found [here.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#list11)