# Create xml file and save it in internal storage android

Tags: android

I want to check in the android internal storage if `new.xml` exists(which will be created by me) then it should return me a handle for it and i may be easily able to append new data to it.If it doesn't exists create a new one and add data to it.

My xml file structure will be simple like this.

```
<root>
    <record>a</record>
    <record>b</record>
    <record>c</record>
</root>
```

If the file is there I will only add a new record to it.But if doesn't than I will create a new file and add the first record to it.

And How I will be able to read this data in an `arraylist`. An example with code would be great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's rather simple. This will help you:

```java
String filename = "file.txt";

FileOutputStream fos;
fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_APPEND);

XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

serializer.startTag(null, "root");

for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    serializer.startTag(null, "record");
    serializer.text(data);
    serializer.endTag(null, "record");
}

serializer.endDocument();
serializer.flush();

fos.close();
```

To read back data using DOM parser:

```java
FileInputStream fis = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;

fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

char[] inputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
isr.read(inputBuffer);

data = new String(inputBuffer);

isr.close();
fis.close();

/*
* Converting the String data to XML format so
* that the DOM parser understands it as an XML input.
*/

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ArrayList<XmlData> xmlDataList = new ArrayList<XmlData>();

XmlData xmlDataObj;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
DocumentBuilder db;
NodeList items = null;
Document dom;

dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
dom = db.parse(is);

// Normalize the document
dom.getDocumentElement().normalize();

items = dom.getElementsByTagName("record");
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++)
{
    Node item = items.item(i);
    arr.add(item.getNodeValue());
}
```

Comment: So there is no `serializer.endTag(null, "root");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) to get the path to where you can create files. Check if the file exists by creating a file object `File newXml = new File(getFilesDir+"/new.xml")`. Then check if it exists using `if(newXml.exists())`.

To parse the data, refer [dev docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) . As you can see in the XmlPullParser example, it can return a list.

Comment: how to append the data to the existing file ?

Comment: Kindly research well before asking here. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059296/how-to-append-an-xml-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to create file in internal storage and [getFileStreamPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29) for checking if they already exists and working with them

To read data into array just open file stream and use any appropriate XML parser

Comment: how do i append the data to an existing file

Comment: Obtain File via getFileStreamPath, check that it exists, open FileOutputStream and write your data into stream